# Convert text in other encoding qt

Tags: qt

Alert: I am using QByteArray.
I want to ask about which other conversions exist. I am normally using toLatin1 but i would try with others. Example:

```
datoss = "|@|" + ui->textocuenta->text().toLatin1() + "|@|";
```

I repeat again, i am trying to use other conversion. Only that.

Comment: why don't you just look? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1

Comment: i am using QByteArray so i could change the conversion too.???

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - `QTextCodec::availableCodecs()` tells you which encodings you can use; what more do you need?

Comment: yes i need QTextCodec::availableCodecs() Sorry i checked the solution of other member but doesnt work fine So i prefer change encoding.

Answer (score 0):

See [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) class info. Convert your QByteArray to QString, there are multiple conversions:

```
CFStringRef toCFString() const
QString toCaseFolded() const
QString toHtmlEscaped() const
QByteArray  toLatin1() const
QByteArray  toLocal8Bit() const
NSString *  toNSString() const
std::string toStdString() const
std::u16string  toStdU16String() const
std::u32string  toStdU32String() const
std::wstring    toStdWString() const
ushort  toUShort(bool *ok = Q_NULLPTR, int base = 10) const
QVector<uint>   toUcs4() const
QByteArray  toUtf8() const
int toWCharArray(wchar_t *array) const
```

If you are looking for a way to convert your indexed data from your  QWidget in to  a QByteArray, just use:

```
const QString indexed =  QString("|@|%1|@|").arg(ui->textocuenta->text());
datoss = indexed.toLatin1();
```

Comment: hi i could avoid this conversion or use other Unicode or something. I need one example for this: datoss = "|@|" + ui->textocuenta->text().toLatin1() + "|@|" it is important for me thanks datoss is a QByteArray